# How to avoid "A Chart may only have up to 256 series" issue (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to build bubble chart from a scratch in excel. Below is piece of code I'm using. Everything works fine until SeriesCollection.NewSeries reaches 256. Then I'm getting error message: A Chart may only have up to 256 series.

Can you anybody help me, how to avoid this issue. Is there any more elegant solution? Thanks a lot for any of your hint or advice.

**Source code for my bubble chart:**

```
With wsAnalytics.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=0, Width:=995, Top:=0, Height:=580)
  For i = 1 To Range("Config_BubbleChartData").Rows.Count
    .Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .Chart.SeriesCollection(i).name = Range("Config_BubbleChartData").Rows(i).Cells(1, 1)
    .Chart.SeriesCollection(i).XValues = Range("Config_BubbleChartData").Rows(i).Cells(1, 3)
    .Chart.SeriesCollection(i).Values = Range("Config_BubbleChartData").Rows(i).Cells(1, 4)

    Select Case BubbleColor
        Case 1
        .Chart.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Case 2
        .Chart.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        Case 3
        .Chart.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    End Select
    If i = 1 Then .Chart.ChartType = xlBubble3DEffect
    .Chart.SeriesCollection(i).BubbleSizes = "=" &     Range("Config_BubbleChartData").Parent.name _
            & "!" & Range("Config_BubbleChartData").Rows(i).Cells(1, 5).Address(1, 1, xlR1C1)
  Next i
```

Comment: if you are trying to have more then 256 series in a chart, it's not possible, as that is the limit Excel imposes. If you are *trying to avoid* some other issue, please restate your question :)

Comment: First I'd like to avoid this issue :-)

Comment: *First I'd like to avoid this issue* - which issue, the 255 chart series limit? It's not possible [See Data series in one chart in this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-CA36E2DC-1F09-4620-B726-67C00B05040F)

Comment: Why do you think you need them as separate series for each row?

Comment: Rory, I'm also using piece of code late for access to particular bubble (row) for color changing.

Answer (score 1):

You only need as many series as you have colors. Certainly you don't need more than 255 colors, since no human would be able to distinguish more than a dozen in a cluttered bubble chart.

Set up the data with four columns for X, Y, bubble size, and bubble color. Append another column for each color in the bubble color column, and use the color name as the column header. Use an IF formula in these columns to put the Y value for each color into the appropriate column.

In my example, I have X and Y in columns A and B, bubble size and color in C and D, plus the bubble color names in E1:G1. The formula in cell E2 is

`=IF($D2=E$1,$B2,NA())`

and I've filled this into E2:G16. The result is the Y value if the column header matches the color, and #N/A otherwise, which will not plot.

[image: data for bubble chart]

Select A2:C19 and create the bubble chart (top left chart).

Click the Select Data button on the Chart Tools > Design tab of the ribbon, select the only series in the chart, and Edit it, so cell E1 is used for the name, and E2:E16 is used for the Y values. Keep A2:A16 as the X values and C2:C16 as the bubble size. This series will have the default color for the first series, which in Excel 2013 and 2016 is blue (top right chart).

Stay in or return to the Edit Data dialog, and add a series. Use cell F1 for series name, A2:A16 as X values, F2:F16 as Y values, and C2:C16 as the bubble size. This series will use the default second color, orange (bottom left chart).

Add one more series, use cell G1 for series name, A2:A16 as X values, G2:G16 as Y values, and C2:C16 as the bubble size. This series uses the default third color, gray (bottom right chart).

Note that all series use the same X values and bubble sizes, but different Y values.

[image: evolution of bubble chart]